# Geoserver styles - changed feature icon on mouse over

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, openlayers

I am using OpenGeo and OpenLayers 3. I managed to set a WMS layer from PostGis (Configure new SQL view) where I show points from coordinates I have in database.
I also managed (following tutorial on [docs.geoserver](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/points.html#point-as-graphic)) to set the custom icon as graphic.

The next step is that this graphic icon changed on mouse over. I understand, that only image is transferred to client from GeoServer since I am using WMS. But there must be a way to do that. Is it? I think I must use WFS, but maybe I am wrong. What then? There are not plenty examples for OpenLayers3.

Icon style:

```
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <PointSymbolizer>
         <Graphic>
           <ExternalGraphic>
             <OnlineResource
               xlink:type="simple"
               xlink:href="image.png" />
             <Format>image/png</Format>
           </ExternalGraphic>
           <Size>32</Size>
         </Graphic>
       </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use WFS to get the effect you want. Unfortunately, I haven't looked at much version 3 code, but in version 2, you would create client-side default and highlight styles with an icon. You would then add a select control to the layer with "hover" set to true.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Yes I already did this in OpenLayers 2. But I am building a page, that will go online in a year, so I decided to use OpenLayers 3.